# check if click is true on eventListener

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const btn = button.addEventListener("click", run);

button.disabled = true;

function run() {
  if (btn.onclick == true && button.disabled == true) {
    alert('the button is clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button"></button>
</body>

<script type="module" src="./resources/js/index.js"></script>

</html>
```

I have a button with an addEventListener("click", run); on it. Now I would like to check if the button is clicked yes or no. I know you can check this with onclick but this doesnt seem to work and returns undefined.

I have a function were I disable the button for x minutes. when the buttons is disabled and a user tries to click on it i want to show an alert.

Comment: Typo. `=` is an assignment not a comparison.

Comment: i tried doing it with '=', '==' & '===' but none of these 3 works. it will still say that btn is undefined.

Comment: `btn.onclick` holds a function that runs when the user clicks on the button, it's not a true/false value.

Comment: then how could i check if the button is clicked or not? since i thought this would be done with true or false.

Comment: Buttons don't have a clicked state. You're confusing them with checkboxes.

Comment: It's clicked if the `run` function runs at all.

Comment: Right, the function runs when they click on the button. Why do you think you need a condition?

Comment: ah okay so it isnt possible to check if this button is clicked at all? because i cant check if the function has run because this wont be possible with the rest of my code

Comment: @Barmar i would like to show an alert when the button is clicked at a certain time

Comment: If you want to know if the button has been clicked in the past, set a global variable and test that.

Comment: `button.addEventListener()` doesn't return anything. So you're setting `btn` to `undefined`.

Comment: I edit the post with a bit more information, i cant check if the button is pressed in the past since i only want to check on a specific time

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `if` statement. The event listener runs whenever the button is clicked.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener("click", run);

function run() {
  alert('the button is clicked');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Click me</button>
</body>

<script type="module" src="./resources/js/index.js"></script>

</html>
```